# Deriving LST in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am following a tutorial to calculate the mean Land Surface Temperature from multiple Landsat8 collection 2 level 2 band ST_B10 images in the google earth engine. However, the output did not cover the whole study area I've defined. I pasted the code here.

Can you tell me what caused this?

[image]

```
var DATE_RANGE = ee.Filter.dayOfYear(182, 243);

var YEAR_RANGE = ee.Filter.calendarRange(2013, 2022,'year');

var STUDYBOUNDS = AOI;

var DISPLAY = true;

Map.setOptions('SATELLITE');
    
Map.setCenter (104.066002, 30.657000, 10); 
   
var LC08_bands = ['ST_B10', 'QA_PIXEL']; 

//****************** CLOUD MASK FUNCTION *****************//
function cloudMask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3)
    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4));
  return image.updateMask(mask.not());
}

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .select('ST_B10', 'QA_PIXEL')
  .filterBounds(STUDYBOUNDS)
  .filter(DATE_RANGE)
  .filter(YEAR_RANGE)
  .map(cloudMask);
    
var filtered_L8 = L8.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 20));


function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B10').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0) // Scale factors for Kelvin
  .subtract(273.15); // Scale factor for degrees Celsius
  return image.addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

var landsatST = filtered_L8.map(applyScaleFactors);

//****************** CALCULATE MEAN SURFACE TEMPERATURE *****************//
var mean_LandsatST = landsatST.mean();

var clip_mean_ST = mean_LandsatST.clip(STUDYBOUNDS);

print(clip_mean_ST, 'Mean ST clipped to study area');

var values_ST = clip_mean_ST.select("ST_B10"); 

Map.addLayer(clip_mean_ST, {
  bands: "ST_B10", 
  min: 28, max: 47, 
  palette: ['blue','white','red']}, "ST", DISPLAY);
```